# How to modify my pointer value in this exemple?

Tags: c, string, parsing, pointers

I am trying to move my char pointer along my char array (a string), it doesn't work and I don't understand why.

My char array looks like this `"5,true,-12,..."`

Here is my code :

```
local_length = get_param_length(jump_next_param(param));
```

- local length is the param's length (without the comma)
- param is the string i want to parse

With the exemple I gave, before the line I wrote, local_length = 1 (5 length).
After the line I wrote, local_length = 4 (true length).

But param still pointing to 5 and I want it pointing to t

Here is the code of jump_next_param():

```
static char* jump_next_param(char *param){
    uint32_t jump_length = get_param_length(param);
    param += jump_length + 1;
return param;}
```

Comment: Need more context.

Comment: "param still pointing to 5" is not demonstrated.  Post a [mcve]

Comment: In C all parameters are passed to functions by making a copy of the values. Nothing will be visible after you left the function.

Comment: Use `char **param` in your function and update `*param`

Answer (score 0):

What you really have here is an XY problem. You want help parsing individual items out of a comma-delimited list.  If you don't have to worry about quote-surrounded strings containing commas, you can just use `strchr` for that:

```
char *list = "first,second,third,fourth,fifth";
char *p = list;
char *q = list;

do
{
    p = strchr(q, ',');
    printf("%.*s\n", (ptrdiff_t)(p - q), q);
    q = p;
    p++, q++;
}
while (p != NULL);
```